# Synchronize FBA Users (ASPNET Membership Databse in SQL Server) in User Profile Service

Tags: sharepoint-2013, fba, sharepoint-userprofile

I have FBA configured in a web application (SharePoint 2013) with ASPNET Membership Database in SQL Server.

Now I need to have FBA users (SQL - Membership Database users) synchronized in User Profile Service. Please let me know if there is any way to avail this.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get any solution for this. I also have same requirement.